# Catholicism closed, anybody mind if I just ask those questions here?

Tags: discussion, catholicism

Looks like my favorite church isn't getting a [stack exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27685/catholicism).  There were lots of good questions on that proposal there, anyone want to help me ask them here?

---

Also, should questions like [Praying the Liturgy of the Hours in private; out loud](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/praying-the-liturgy-of-the-hours-in-private-out-loud) be tagged with [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism)?  Catholics would probably be the only ones who know what I'm talking about, but the content of the question is regarding a practice that would be right or wrong regardless of the tradition the answer it comes out of.

Comment: Catholicism is [included](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/132/christianity-se-vs-survivor) in Christianity, so go right ahead! :)

Comment: I *was* wondering why there were so few Catholicism questions...

Comment: You should add an announcement / discussion thread over on that proposal telling people they can bring their questions and expertise here.

Comment: @caleb http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/go-ask-your-questions-at-christianity

Comment: The whole point of closing Catholicism was that the questions could be asked here.

Comment: As a Catholic, one of the most interesting questions I was ever asked was "What is the difference between a Catholic and a Christian?" >.<

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go right ahead! I think we'd love to see more Catholic questions (and experts) around here.

My only comment, not to you but to other people browsing Area 51 proposals, is that scope questions from the proposal cannot usually just be copy/pasted into a real site and have them be a good question. You have to frame them, include background, scoped them to a perspective, etc. We've seen a few people just copy the questions verbatim and it's not appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a great site for them!

My only comment is that I would make sure to specify if you're seeking Catholic-only viewpoints.  It will help eliminate the noise and high-votes from Protestant/LDS/JH/atheist/etc. answers.

(Unless, of course, you're looking to open the question up to all viewpoints.)