# Are denominationally specific questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

Are denominationally specific questions allowed?  For example: despite being a life-long (I am 38 this month) Catholic the notion of "the common priesthood of the Faithful" is, at best, vague to me. I would like to learn more about this if anyone can clue me into it, but I only want answers that appertain to me as a Catholic.

Are questions restricting the answers to being Catholic-only allowed on Christianity.SE?

(I'm not saying that a non-Catholic cannot give a very good Catholic answer; I would only be looking for an answer that is based on Catholic teaching and applies to me as a Catholic.)

Comment: Questions from specific denominations are in fact *encouraged* on this site. It makes it far easier to pick an objective correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!

Just point your question directly at the Catholic tradition and perhaps tag it as well. Answerers can believe anything they want, but the answers themselves will be expected to cover only the scope of Catholic doctrine.

In fact, these are more encouraged than non denominationally specific questions.

Comment: I'm not sure you answered the question, depending on whether it meant that Catholics only could answer, or answers must express Catholic theology.

Answer (score 5):

Also, check out these other meta posts

- [Should I tag with Catholicism when the question is obviously about Catholicism?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/801/should-i-tag-with-catholicism-when-the-question-is-obviously-about-catholicism)
- [Catholicism closed, anybody mind if I just ask those questions here?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/533/catholicism-closed-anybody-mind-if-i-just-ask-those-questions-here)

Everyone's been pretty nice on the site even though Catholics are a pretty small minority.  I have yet to have anyone say, "I don't care what some priest says". Like they might (do) on Facebook.

The vague questions, like the one on [Ephesians we both answered](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5830/how-can-we-know-what-is-meant-by-a-church-without-blemish) today, are really not good fits for the site, I actually shouldn't have bothered to answer it.  The OP needs to state the source of the doctrine they're looking for answers from or else it becomes a popularity contest.

Answer (score -1):

### 'This question is only for Catholics'

Today a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90608/according-to-catholicism-why-must-there-be-only-one-pure-necessary-being-or-nec?rq=1) specified "This question is only for Catholics."

This is unacceptable to me. The issue goes to @Caleb's answer above. Caleb says "yes absolutely" to "are questions restricting the answers to being Catholic-only allowed." But the query can be read two ways: a) the answers should be an expression of Catholic views or b) the answers must only be written by Catholics. Caleb says "Answerers can believe anything they want," so that much is clear.

I have flagged the question and hope moderators will gently educate the questioner to avoid religious discrimination against qualified participants.

Comment: You can always provide an acceptable edit, as long it respects the OP's intention about what is being asked. According to Catholicism, ..

Comment: The site is biased towards Trinitarianism, and in particular toward Catholicism. I would just ignore the 'only for Catholics' if you want to provide an answer from the POV of Catholicism.